# Cleaner callbacks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback

If I want to break a callback implementation out of a method's parameter footprint for cleaner code I can do (for example)

```
foo.bar(a, callback(), b);
function callback() {
  stuff;
}
```

instead of

```
foo.bar(a, function() {
  stuff;
}, b);
```

But what do I do if the method passes something into the callback like three.js's loader functions? (http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/OBJMTLLoader)

```
foo.bar(callback(object));
function callback(object) {
  object.stuff();
}
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why would you pass `callback()` instead of `callback`?

Comment: `foo.bar(function() { callback(object); })`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  The format should be:

```
foo.bar(callback);
function callback(object) {
  object.stuff();
}
```

Comment: but,.do  you know why?

Comment: But no. `foo.bar` does not know it is supposed to call the callback with `object`, or what `object` to call the callback with.

Comment: It does though. Foo is specifically passing in a variable that it created, so I wouldn't be able to specify anyway. This is currently working in my implementation.

Comment: @Joel, if I had to guess I'd say by including () I'm actually passing in the result of that function (calling it), while without the parentheses I'm passing in the function itself?

Comment: all right @GameKyuubi X), i belive that no just a correct  answer will help us, but the knowledge make we grow up.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 snippets you've posted are actually different - when you pass an anonymous function as an argument it isn't run immediately, but in the "foo.bar" function itself. However, when you pass it as "callback()", that function runs immediately (it is useful in some cases, for example: if the function returns another function). So, pass it without "()".

For example:

```
function a(){
   alert(1);
}
function b(callback){
   callback(); //run the callback function.
}

b(a);
```

And, if you want to see an example of the second option:

```
function a(){
   return function() {
      alert(1);
   };
}

a()(); //Alert
b(a()); //Alert
b(a) //nothing happens
```

Comment: Is there a name for the difference between these functions?

Comment: No. It's just a thing that belonges to function's returns and callbacks.